# Recursive method to evaluate expressions just work when method is called once

Tags: java, stack, evaluation, is-empty

I'm writing a code to valuate math expressions. The code just works when I call the methode once. But I have more than one expression to evaluate and it just break when I call the method more than two times. I get the following error:

```
-2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at Evaluate.parse(Evaluate.java:58)
    at Evaluate.main(Evaluate.java:11)
```

I see that the code gives me the expected result (the -2) but what I'm doing wrong regarding the methode that gives me this error

My code:

```
public class Evaluate {

    static Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();
    static Stack<Integer> vals = new Stack<Integer>();
    static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parse("(4-(7-1))"));
        System.out.println(parse("8"));
        System.out.println(parse("((1+1)*(2*2))"));
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println(parse("(6/(3/2))"));

    }

    private static int parse(String expression) {
        char[] tokens = expression.toCharArray();

        while (tokens.length > i) {
            char s = tokens[i];
            if (s == '(') {
                ops.push(tokens[i]);
            } else if (s == '+' || s == '-' || s == '*' || s == '/') {

                while (!ops.empty() && hasPrecedence(tokens[i], ops.peek()))
                    vals.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), vals.pop(), vals.pop()));
                ops.push(s);

            } else if (s == ')') {
                char op = ops.pop();
                int v = vals.pop();
                while (ops.peek() != '(')
                    vals.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), vals.pop(), vals.pop()));
                ops.pop();

                if (op == '+') {
                    v = vals.pop() + v;
                } else if (op == '-') {
                    v = vals.pop() - v;
                } else if (op == '*') {
                    v = vals.pop() * v;
                } else if (op == '/') {
                    v = vals.pop() / v;
                }

                vals.push(v);
            } else {
                vals.push(Character.getNumericValue(s));
            }
            i++;
        }

        while (!ops.empty())
            vals.push(applyOp(ops.pop(), vals.pop(), vals.pop()));

        return vals.pop();
    }

    public static boolean hasPrecedence(char op1, char op2) {
        if (op2 == '(' || op2 == ')')
            return false;
        if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-'))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // A utility method to apply an
    // operator 'op' on operands 'a'
    // and 'b'. Return the result.
    public static int applyOp(char op, int b, int a) {
        switch (op) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
            if (b == 0)
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot divide by zero");
            return a / b;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It is a good time for you to use a debugger and step through to debug the issue

Comment: I am new to it. I know that the error is caused because the length of the stack is empty and there is nothing more to pop. But I cant do anything with the information, thats why I wrote a question

Comment: @user7 i already did it